# Spark on EMR - Downloading Different Jar Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, jar, amazon-emr

I am downloading, using bootstrap, a mysql jar file to the spark/jars folder.  I use the following:

```
sudo aws s3 cp s3://buck/emrtest/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars
```

Everything downloads correctly but I eventually get a provisioning error and the cluster terminates.   I get this error :

```
On 5 slave instances (including i-0505b9beda64e9,i-0f85f4664e1359 and i-00d346a73f717b), application provisioning failed
```

It doesn't fail on my master node but fails on my slave nodes. I have checked my logs and it doesn't give me any information. Why does this fail and how would I go about downloading this jar file to every node in a bootstrap fasion?

Thanks!

Comment: [Check your logs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/application-provisioning-failed/?nc1=h_ls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  First off, the logging for this is not there.  The master node launches on a failure.

I was retrieving a file in a private s3 bucket. Note: aws configs do not get inherited in your EMR cluster.